# html audio keeps getting interrupted

Tags: javascript, html, chromium, html5-audio, kiosk

I have a web based kisok, running on a raspberry pi, which plays sound continuously and displays information. Problem is that the audio gets interrupted when other things are happening. You hear lots of short pauses. For example, if I'm running a slideshow, there are lots of pauses when it's presumably loading the next image.

Here's simplified code which exhibits the same problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<audio id='audio' controls>
 <source src="get-file.php?id=148440" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<br>

<img id='img1' src='' style='max-width:100%; max-height:80%;' />

<script>
setInterval(function(){
        url = "get-file.php?rand=fam&date=" + new Date().getTime();
        img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        img1.src = url;
    }, 5000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can manually press the Play button to start playing audio. The sound will be interrupted regularly by the sideshow.

Is there any way to avoid this or can anyone explain why it happens?

I've noticed that if the audio player is isolated in a separate tab (chrome) it is unaffected by the other activities. But I would much prefer to keep everything on one page if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine what is happening is the sound may be 2s long and if you get multiple "pings" this must completely play through still. The bypass is to pause the sound, set currentTime to 0 and re-play each message.

The result is that if you have ten messages coming in real quick, you'll hear 10 alerts but perhaps 0.1s 0.1s 0.1s ... 2s

```
mysound.pause();
mysound.currentTime = 0;
mysound.play();
```

Comment: Hopefully this helps somewhat. I write chat sites and implement this so all messages are heard. I would suggest though to not be annoyed to write muting functions say if you're getting over 10 messages a second (make it more friendly on the ears)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here, but I should clarify the mqtt messages are just text based. There are no other audio elements on the page. Just one <audio> element that gets interrupted by other (non-audio related) activities. Thanks

Comment: The MQTT means nothing here, it's just routing messages you pipe through. Your client however  is the question.

Comment: Why are you using audio elements and how are you triggering the play? Would assume something isn't right there and would maybe need to see some code.

Comment: Receiving an MQTT message is just an instance where audio is interrupted. To try and keep the question more focused I removed it from my question and provided some code.